# How To Properly Remove Click Handler?

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling pretty hard with this problem.

I got a div for the navigation and a div where a page is loaded:

```
<div class="page"></div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="page1">Page 1</div>
  <div class="page2">Page 2</div>
</div>
```

The pages are loaded - when a user clicks on the specific div - through ajax load() method. "Page 1" is the home page which basically contains two divs:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**This is what I want:**
=> When I click on a .box div - this .box div gets a class called .active.
=> When I click on this .box div again - the .active class from this .box div should be removed.

It works pretty fine with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".box", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

**BUT...**
When I switch to "Page 2" and back to "Page 1" I showed above and I click on a .box div the "click" is fired twice - so just with one click on a .box div, the .box div gets an .active class and the .active class is removed.

What am I doing wrong here?

**[EDIT]**
The pages are loaded with AJAX:

```
$('.page').load('page1.php');
$('.page1').click(function() {
  $('.page').load('page1.php');
});
$('.page2').click(function() {
  $('.page').load('page2.php');
});
```

Comment: When exactly are you calling that javascript logic?

Comment: That simple code alone is not wrong. The dirty bug is elsewhere. You must try to debug why you bind the event twice

Comment: How exactly do you "switch to Page 2" here?  Your "pages" appear to just be `<div>` elements, not actual links to other pages.  I suspect a more complete example may be necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The point here being that that logic should only be executed once, because you are creating a delegate event binding on the document.  There is no need to execute it multiple times, and in fact, doing so creates the duplicate bindings.

Comment: @David Please check out my EDIT.

Comment: Is that document ready logic inside the pages loaded?

Comment: @Taplar No. The logic is on the container page called "container.php" that contains the navigation (.nav) and page container div (.page). So the jQuery is not loaded on every page.

Comment: @Taplar The problem is that when I switch pages x times, the jQuery is somehow fired x times too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this will answer to your problem. But I highly not recommend it because you'd rather fix the root of the bug, which is a critical JS logic.

So the "work-around", to unset the handler and bind the event with a namespace.

```
$(document).off("click.box").on("click.box", ".box", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

When a content is loaded using ajax, you should always use an element as the root of the ajax content like `$('.myAjaxRoot').on('click')`

It is highly not recommended to always rely on the `$(document)` especially when the JS is loaded through AJAX many times.

```
$(function() {
    //put all this stuffs inside page1.php so when the DOM is cleared from AJAX, so does the events
    $(".content").on("click", ".box", function() {...});
});
```

Comment: So you mean `$(".page").on("click", ".box",  function() {...});`?

Comment: I assume you put your JS inside "page1.php". So no, you should bind to a root element inside the content of "page1.php"

Comment: No, the JS is at the bottom of the "container.php" that contains the navigation (.nav) and page container (.page). On "page1.php" is basically only a .content div that contains some text. But when I write `$(".content").on("click", ".box", function() {...});` inside the "container.php" the click jQuery is not fired. Should I write all this code inside a `$(document).ready(function() {...});`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you called that JS many times. Just put an "alert" before `$(document).on('click')` and see how many times it fired. And use that method `.off(click)` mentioned. Wrap your JS with `$(function(){ ... })` as document.ready

Comment: It worked with binding to a root element inside the "page1.php" => `$(".content").on("click", ".box", function() {...});`. But I don't understand - why? Could you explain a little further please? Because there is no .box div inside the .content div on "page1.php".

Comment: The problem NOW is that the .box div is not reacting on click on mobile iOS. And it only works as long as I got an alert before the click call and one inside the click call. Very strange.

Comment: First, page1 is just an example. You should put the JS event handlers inside the page which contains the .box div. It could be page2, 3, you name it. Second, because everything inside page1 is loaded through AJAX, we should apply the JS for elements inside that content, like a separate region. So when you click on page2, every DOM inside page1 is cleared as well as the JS events, which make your page pristine. Dynamic events should only be attached to the closest common parent if possible and avoid blind `$(document).on()` to prevent many problems

Comment: @arif try to clear your iOS cache. Make sure to always wrap `$(function(){ ... })` or put JS at the bottom of file and after HTML elements

Comment: Alright. Should I put `$(".content").on("click", ".box", function() {...});` inside a  `$(document).ready(function() {...});` in "page1.php"?

Comment: Not all `.content` in the whole web page, just `.page1 .content` inside this specific page1

Comment: Thanks! But now the problem is that after adding the script to "page1.php" and removing it from "container.php", the jquery which is located on the bottom of the "container.php" isn't loaded somehow anymore after switching pages. This is the way it works: `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on("click", ".box", function() { $(".box").toggleClass("active"); }); });` I have no idea if this is the right way now. Because `$(document).ready(function() { $('.page').on("click", ".box", function() { $(".box").toggleClass("active"); }); });` doesn't fire after page switch.

Comment: You don't need to fire after a page switch. Register the event once to element `.page` is enough.